# How to add Python Libraries/Modules to Casio CG50 Calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, calculator, micropython

Got a Casio CG50 calculators and there are some useful programs that I have on my laptop written in Python that won't work on the calculator due to it running Micropython by default and the lack of libraries. So is there a way to possibly add modules or libraries from the full Python version to the calculator?

Comment: Regular Python modules aren't compatible with MicroPython. You'll ned to re-implement your desired functionality in MicroPython (or find existing modules that someone else has written that do the same thing). If the platform is running MicroPython it is unlikely you would be able to run regular Python on it.